# How to launch my web page in a web hosting domain?

Tags: html, xml, web

Am very to new to web development.

I have the web pages; web pages are developed in html, CSS Style sheet.

For Example
I have the ftp domain or crystal.com for hosting my web page

For hosting my web pages, I have to create setup file for hosting my web page or simply post my html files.

Can any one tell the procedure, what are the things I have to do for the web hosting?

Note: I am not asking about Web hosting domain. Already I have the domain, but how to post my html files in that domain.

Need Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ftp is the best way to publish your files. Use something like [filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org) and read the help docs. You will upload the files to a folder (usually something like public_html) and then the files correspond to your domain. Example:

you upload a file:

/public_html/blog/index.htm

then go to your site:

http://www.yourdomain.com/blog/index.htm

Here is [a good tutorial on FTP](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ftp/). It's pretty easy once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your domain provider's DNS server to point to the server where your files are located.  For example, I have my domain (brasee.com) through GoDaddy.com, and I host my site locally.  So I go to the GoDaddy website and update their DNS server to forward brasee.com requests to my server's IP address.